# Why doesn't my Macbook detect network after sleep?

Tags: macos, wifi, network

every time that my 2007 macbook with lion goes to sleep, either manually (closing the lid) or timing out, i have to restart my computer to connect to the wireless network.  It fails to detect any networks at all until I restart, then it connects to my default network no problem.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Clear the network out and re-setup it.

Otherwise, I've run into this issue before, what brand of router are you using? And does it happen with other networks apart from this one?

Related: [Why doesn't Airport reconnect after sleep or shutdown?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34552/why-doesnt-airport-reconnect-after-sleep-or-shutdown)

Comment: I'll give it a shot. But it won't recognize any networks after sleep. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apple claims to have addressed this issue with the [OS X 10.7.3 update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5048) which, amongst other things, has a fix to:

> Resolve a Wi-Fi connection issue when waking from sleep

Ars Technica reports that some people have had [problems with the update](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2012/02/problems-with-the-os-x-1073-update-combo-updater-to-the-rescue.ars) but they are resolved by reinstalling using the [Combo Updater](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on Retina running Mountain Lion.

After waking from sleep, WiFi doesn't automatically reconnect although it connects just fine when I manually select the network from the list.

I found a working fix [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=14921285&postcount=54), kudos to Morris for posting.
For convenience, I reproduce his post here:

> The first step is to create a new 'Location' under 'Network Preferences' and use that as default. I have deleted all old locations, don't know if that is necessary though.
>
> The second step is to follow Apple's advice in [Troubleshooting Wi-Fi issues in OS X Lion and Mac OS X v10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4628?viewlocale=en_US).
>
> Expand the Solution section under **Symptom: The network connection drops unexpectedly** and follow the steps listed under **Symptom: After restarting or waking from sleep, my computer might not connect to the Internet**.
>
> Just make sure you write down all the passwords for the networks you want to keep as deleting the keys in keychain will permanently remove them.